# names of the arguments in a R widget

Tags: r, gwidgets

Below is an artificial example of a R widget

```
library(gWidgets)
options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")

f <- function(file, max.rows){
    dat <- read.table(file, nrows=max.rows)
return(max(dat[,]))
}

lst <- list() 
    lst$action <- list(beginning="f(",ending=")")
    lst$arguments$file <- list(type="gfilebrowse")
    lst$arguments$max.rows <- list(type="gedit", text=-1)

ggenericwidget(lst, container=gwindow("Example"))
```

[image: widget]

The name of each argument in the R widget is the same as its name in the R function. Is it possible to only change the name appearing in the R widget ? For instance, I would like to write *"Maximum number of rows"* in the R widget instead of "max.rows".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I could come up with was the following, working from [this post](http://4dpiecharts.com/2010/10/06/creating-guis-in-r-with-gwidgets/). I'm not sure if you're willing to create the widgets from scratch, but it seems to me that it's the only way to manually choose labels for your arguments.

```
library(gWidgets)
options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")

f <- function(file, max.rows){
   dat <- read.table(file, nrows=max.rows)
   return(max(dat[,]))
}

win <- gwindow("Example")

grp.text <- ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, container = win)
lbl.text <- glabel("Maximum Lines: ", container = grp.text)
insert.text <- gedit(-1, container = grp.text)

grp.file <- ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, container = win)
lbl.file <- glabel("File: ", container = grp.file)
browse.file <- gfilebrowse(container = grp.file)

read <- gbutton(text="Go", container = grp.file, 
    handler = function(h, ...) {
            cat(f(svalue(browse.file), 
                as.numeric(svalue(insert.text))));
    }
)
```

This is a minimal example; there would have to be some error-checking along the way.

Comment: That seems to work but I don't like the output: with my widget the R code "f(file=..., max.rows=...) " appears in the console, not with yours. I will think about your way and try to get something closest to what I want. Thanks.

Comment: What Edward shows is the best solution -- just make your own widgets. the `ggenericwidget` function is pretty limited. In `gWidgets2` I dropped this function. The `gformlayout` container makes such things fairly easy. Here is an example https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgets2/blob/master/inst/examples/ex-gformlayout.R. As well, the main functionality of `ggenericwidget` is contained in this example https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgets2/blob/master/inst/examples/ex-generate-gui.R

Comment: @jverzani Thanks a lot. I think it is not a good idea to drop the ggenericwidget() function. Please listen to my story. I am working in a statisticians team in which I am the only real R user (my colleagues are SAS users). I gave a little presentation about gWdigtes. I said to my colleagues: "hey! take a R function, use ggenericwidget and look, the widget is done !". They were impressed and charmed. Then I add: "this is the basic way, it's possible to do a more sophisticated and pretty widget". They wouldn't have been such enthusiastic if I had shown them a code such yours or Edward's code...

Answer (score 1):

To flesh out my comment to Edward's answer, this is how `gformlayout` from `gWidgets2` can be used, though using `gtable` directly might also be the way to go.

```
library(gWidgets2)
options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")

f <- function(file, max.rows){
    dat <- read.table(file, nrows=max.rows)
    message("Calling max")
    print(max(dat[,]))
}

## containers
w <- gwindow("Example", visible=FALSE)
fr <- gframe("Arguments", horizontal=FALSE, cont=w)       # optional frame
fl <- gformlayout(cont=fr)
## widgets
select_file <- gfilebrowse(cont=fl, label="File")
max_rows <- gedit(-1, cont=fl, label="maximum number of rows", coerce.with=as.numeric)
## button
bg <- ggroup(cont=fr)
addSpring(bg)
btn <- gbutton("ok", cont=bg)

addHandlerClicked(btn, function(h,...) {
  l <- svalue(fl) ## a named list by the labels,
  do.call(f, setNames(l, c("file", "max.rows"))) ## change names for do.call
})
visible(w) <- TRUE
```

I haven't put `gWidgets2` on CRAN yet (still on github), but will at some point. This is where any new features will be made for `gWidgets` going forward.

Answer (score -1):

The alternative to the big solution from @user1546302 uses back ticks:
(Note that there were several unmatched brackets in your original post. I tried to correct this, but SO refused because it were not enough characters changes).

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")

f <- function(file, max.rows){
  dat <- read.table(file, nrows=max.rows)
  max(dat[,])
}

lst <- list() 
lst$action <- list(beginning="f(",ending=")")
lst$arguments$file <- list(type="gfilebrowse")
lst$arguments$`max rows` <- list(type="gedit",text=-1)

ggenericwidget(lst, container=gwindow("Example"))
```

Comment: Thanks but this cannot work because "max rows" is not the name of the argument in f. It yiels the following error message: Houston, we have a problem with: f(file='C:\\example.txt', max rows=-1)

Comment: True. I did not check the function, only the look